# symfony2 createQueryBuilder returns error call to member function

Tags: symfony, query-builder

I'm trying to grab a choice from another bundles entity. This always results in an error and I want to understand why:(

I'm trying to built a form:

```
...
->add('client_id', 'entity', array(
    'class'    => 'PrUserBundle:Client',
    'property' => 'name',
    'required' => true,
    'label'    => $this->get('translator')->trans('staff.location'),
))
...
```

This results in an error:

```
Error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in 
    /var/www/symfony/webprojekt/src/Pr/AdressBundle/Entity/Adress.php line 165
```

And this is the function of line 165:

```
public function getClientId()
{
    return $this->client->getId();
}
```

What am I doing wrong? It is confusing me a bit

EDIT: 
I'm using a ManyToOne for the client

```
    /**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Pr\UserBundle\Entity\Client")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="client_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * @var Client
 */
private $client;
```

Comment: i updated my answer , sorry for previous one , i was having a call while answering you and didn t read correctly :D

Comment: Do you have an association set up between address and client or are they separate tables? Also you don't need to use the `translator` service for your label as it is translated automatically with the domain set in your form type (it defaults to messages).

Comment: OH, thank for the hint with the translator. How should I add the label? like array("label"=> my.label) ?

I edit my question and updated the entity relation

Comment: Yeah, that's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form should be using the `client` field rather than `client_id`.
`client_id` is the field on the database to store the foreign key (from the `client` table) but it is not actually usable via the ORM.

When you are using the entity field it generates the association for your rather than just setting the id/foreign key.

Your `address` model should just have the `getClient` and `setClient` as (for this issue) it doesn't really need to know about what is actually going on with the `client` model.

To then get the client id you would us something along the lines of..

```
if (null === $client = $address->getClient()) {
    throw new \Exception('Address has no client attached');
}

$id = $client->getId();
```

Comment: Thats it. I didn't see the wood for the trees :):)

Now it works. I simply used the wrong entity name :( But I'm happy anyway, because of the translation hint :):)